# MVC 3 Globalization - Australian Currency

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, globalization

I have problem with austalian culture. I set this by the code:

```
        string id = "en-AU";
        string ret = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"] ?? "/";
        string culture = CultureHelper.GetValidCulture(id);
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
        if (cookie != null)
            cookie.Value = culture;
        else {
            cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture");
            cookie.HttpOnly = false;
            cookie.Value = culture;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        }
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

then I want to display a price in AUD:

```
 @String.Format("{0:C}", item.Price
```

but I get e.g `$55.00`. Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are not actually applying the culture anywhere. Something like:

```
CultureInfo userCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture);    
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = userCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = userCulture;
```

Comment: OK, but I still get the $ instead of AUD (I see if I pass the en-AU it returns en-US)

Comment: Use `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture)` instead then, because I think the GetCultureInfo will get you a neutral culture ("en" vs en-AU or en-GB")

Comment: Nope, still gettin'g the $ sign

Comment: Well that's because what the dollar sign is for all dollar currencies (Canadian, Australian, Hong Kong, etc.). You can see in `Region and Language` that when you switch to `English (Australia)` and click on `Additional Settings` and then the `Currency` tab the currency formatting is `$1.1`.

Comment: And if you wish to use the currency name you can either override the default formatting or do your own custom formatting - either way using `RegionInfo.ISOCurrencySymbol`